# How do I compute an ODE with a complex Ginzburg-Landau equation in Julia?

Tags: julia, ode, complex-numbers

first time asking a question here! I am trying to program coupled nonlinear oscillators in Julia using the Vilfan-Duke model. This model uses a complex Ginzburg Landau equation of the form:
z_dot = (i*w + e) * z - B * |z|^2 * z
with z = x - 1/w * i*x_dot
In this model the real part of the equation is equivalent to the displacement of the system and the imaginary part is equivalent to the velocity.
The phase trajectories of a single uncoupled oscillator should look the following:
[Phase Trajectories of Vilfan-Duke oscillator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrMci.png)

My current code is the following:

```
using DifferentialEquations, Plots

   # Constants
   ϵ = -0.5
   B = 0
   ω = 2.0 * 2π # 1/s

   function VilfanDuke(du, u, p, t)
       x, dx = u
       z = x - (1/ω) * (im*dx)
       dz = ((im*ω + ϵ) * z) - (B * abs2(z) * z )
       du[1] = real(dz)
       du[2] = imag(dz) 
   end
    
   # Initial Conditions
   u₀ = [2.0, 0.1]
   tspan = (0.0, 20.0)

   # Define the problem
   prob = ODEProblem(VilfanDuke, u₀, tspan)
   #Solve the problem
   sol = solve(prob, AutoTsit5(Rosenbrock23()))
```

Now the problem is that the system goes into dimensions of e22 or something in that order and if I change the parameters B and e to positive numbers the program aborts after a few timesteps and says the solution is unstable. I have not been working with Julia for long so maybe I misunderstand how complex variables should be used in ODEs? I have previously written a similar program for a Van der Pol oscillator and that worked well, so I suppose the complex variables are the problem here I just can't figure out why.

Comment: You don't need to use a half-complex format as you do with `du[1]` and `du[2]`, your ODE function is allowed to return complex numbers. So you could just return `dz`. I am not familiar with the system you are looking at. Double check if the equation is really correct.

Comment: Agreed, you can either just make `u` a complex number or a vector 2 real numbers where you compute the components, but 2 complex numbers seems incorrect here.